# Running last command with sudo in fish only works if it has no arguments?

Tags: fish

I'm trying to write a function that does the equivalent of `sudo !!` in Bash.  It works, but only when the last command has no arguments.

So far the function is:

```
function s --description "Run last command (or specified command) using sudo"
    if test $argv
        switch $argv[1]
            case '!!'
                command sudo (echo $history[1])
            case '*'
                command sudo $argv
        end
    else
        command sudo fish
    end
end
```

Testing the relevant line:

```
$ command sudo whoami
root
$ whoami
nick
$ command sudo (echo $history[1])
root
```

So far so good, now lets try a command with a few args:

```
$ echo hi >> /etc/motd
An error occurred while redirecting file '/etc/motd'
open: Permission denied
$ command sudo (echo $history[1])
sudo: echo hi >> /etc/motd: command not found
```

Hmm, strange.

Comment: Why are you using `(echo $history[1])` instead of simply `$history[1]`

Comment: @glennjackman it was a bad attempt at fixing some globbing issues I had.  Ended up figuring it out properly in my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it working using eval.

```
function sudo --description 'Run command using sudo (use !! for last command)'
      if test (count $argv) -gt 0
          switch $argv[1]
              case '!!'
                  if test (count $argv) -gt 1
                      set cmd "command sudo $history[1] $argv[2..-1]"
                  else
                      set cmd "command sudo $history[1]"
                  end
              case '*'
                  set cmd "command sudo $argv"
          end
      else
          set cmd "command sudo fish"
      end
      eval $cmd
  end
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem as you, and I fixed it by using `oh-my-fish` 
 (it's a plugin manager for `fish` shell) https://github.com/oh-my-fish/oh-my-fish. You can install it with this command :

```
curl -L https://get.oh-my.fish | fish
```

Then install the plugin `bang-bang` (to allow `!!` and `!$`) with this command :

```
omf install bang-bang
```

Comment: I use oh-my-fish too, but I didn't realize there was a plugin for this, thanks!